# MySQL - How to select the "max" of a "count" column for a table with millions of records?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, group-by

I have a table called `ticket_log` which has millions of records in it. Each ticket log is for a ticket, so the ticket_log table has a `ticket_id` column. I need to find out which ticket has the maximum number of logs.

If the table had only a couple of thousand entries, then the following query would have easily worked -

```
select ticket_id, count(ticket_log_id) as myCount 
from ticket_log 
group by ticket_id 
order by myCount desc limit 1
```

However, when I try running this on a table that has millions of records in it, the query takes forever. Some optimization techniques suggest that we can add a filter of sorts to the query like `where ticket_created > '2014'` for example, but that is not an option.

Given this scenario, how can the query be optimized for a very large number of records?

**Update**: *the query took slightly over an hour to run for the table with millions of records.*

Comment: This could be quite fast if the table had an index on ticket_id or another field. If you don't have any indexes, maybe consider adding one?

Comment: @JAL, an index already exists on ticket_id.

Comment: Is the table MyISAM, InnoDB or another type?

Comment: @JAL, it's InnoDB. The query took slightly over an hour to run.

Comment: Oh. If you search stack overflow, many people have asked similar questions in the past. Apparently, this exact issue is a design limitation of InnoDB.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `tickets` table, then the following might be faster:

```
select ticket_id,
       (select count(*) 
        from ticket_log tl
        where t.ticket_id = tl.ticket_id
      ) as mycount
from tickets t
order by myCount desc
limit 1;
```

This can take advantage of an index on `ticket_log(ticket_id)`.

Comment: Can you please correct the syntax - "myCount" and "tickets t"

Comment: Tried this approach, but had to CTRL C the query when it went past the 1 hour mark.

Comment: @Wes . . . Did you create the proposed index before running the query?

Comment: Gordon, the index already exists. I see Index_type "BTREE" for Column_name "ticket_id" when I do a show index for both tables.

Comment: @Wes . . . It would appear, then, that this approach doesn't fix your problem.  Sometimes the correlated subquery with an index does work better than the `group by`, because it avoids the file sort on a large number of records.